# 2 login areas managed by forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I am developing an asp.net mvc4 application. It has 2 secure areas which users can access. For each area, a different role is required for the user to be in. Its not possible for a user to be in both roles.

The site has 2 separate login pages. I am working with forms authentication to manage the user being logged in and what role they are in.

As the user has 2 seperate login pages, I need the following functionality:

If the users attempts to access area A of the site and not in the necessary, they should be redirect to login page A.

If the users attempts to access area B of the site and not in the necessary, they should be redirect to login page B.

Out of the box, I am not sure if this is possible with forms auth. Could someone explain to me if it is and how it might be achieved?

Comment: why not use and or create this functionality using MasterPages can do a switch{}Case statement based on what comes back from either AD or a Fatabase..?

Comment: Can you make an enum with values of Valid User and invalid user..? and add that to a Session[] or a List, or Hashtable and check the users values that way..? do you have code that you can share for better understanding